# populate checkboxes from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to show a list of climbs, and the user can then select the climbs.

I do it like this:

```
public ActionResult GetClimbs(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    UserProfile user = db.userProfiles
        .Include(i => i.Climbs)

        .Where(i => i.Id == id)
        .Single();
    PopulateAssignedClimbData(user);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(user);
}



private void PopulateAssignedClimbData(UserProfile user)
{
    var allClimbs = db.Climbs;
    var userClimbs = new HashSet<int>(user.Climbs.Select(c => c.climbID));
    var viewModel = new List<AssignedClimb>();
    foreach (var climb in allClimbs)
    {
        viewModel.Add(new AssignedClimb
        {
            ClimbID = climb.climbID,
            Title = climb.Name,
            Assigned = userClimbs.Contains(climb.climbID)
        });
    }
    ViewBag.Climbs = viewModel;
}
```

and for the view I have this:

```
@model ContosoUniversity.Models.UserProfile
@using ContosoUniversity.Source
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm("GetClimbs", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form_Id", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)


        <table>
            <tr>

        @{
            int cnt = 0;
            List<ContosoUniversity.ViewModels.AssignedClimb> climbs = ViewBag.Climbs;


            foreach (var climb in climbs)
            {  
                if (cnt++ % 3 == 0)
                {
                    @:</tr><tr>
                }
                @:<td>
                    <input type="checkbox"
                           name="selectedClimbs"
                           value="@climb.ClimbID"
                           @(Html.Raw(climb.Assigned ? "checked=\"checked\"" : ""))/>

                           @climb.ClimbID @: @climb.Title




                 @:</td>
            }
            @:</tr>
        }
            </table>



    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

But every time I get the message by this line:

```
foreach (var climb in climbs)
```

that climbs is null although I have some climbs in the database.

It also doesn't enter the `GetClimbs` method in the controller.

So the view is a tab, but how to trigger from the tab the action method:             PopulateAssignedClimbData(user); this method is in the Account Controller

Thank you

this is my edit with all the tabs:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Personal information</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Profile Photo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Other Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4">Climbs</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        @Html.Partial("_GetUserProfile", Model)
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        @Html.Partial("_GetProfilePicture", Model)
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        @Html.Partial("_GetOtherImages", Model)
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-4">
        @Html.Partial("_GetClimbTab", Model)
    </div>

</div>
```

this is doing the job:

```
$.get('@Url.Action("PopulateAssignedClimbData", "Account", new { id = Model.Id })', function (data) {
                $('#_GetClimbTab').html(data);
            });
```

Comment: "It also doesn't enter the GetClimbs method in the controller." What do you mean? What action is using the view you posted if not `GetClimbs`? And if it's not `GetClimbs` then why would you expect `GetClimbs` to be called as well?

Comment: Only use version-specific tags if your question is specific to that version.

Comment: The problem is climbs is null.

Comment: Yeah, but it comes from the value of `ViewBag.Climbs` and that property (at least based on the posted code) is only created via your `GetClimbs` action. If that action is not being called, then the `ViewBag` property is never populated, and `climbs` ends up as null.

Comment: Yes, But what is the oter way to pupulate the checkboxes? Thanks

Comment: It's not a problem with your particular method. The problem is that  no data is ever sent to the view because the method you use to populate said data is never utilized. That's what you need to fix.

Comment: yes, oke, but how to ulitze the data to the view? the viewbag name in the controller and view is the same

Comment: Not sure how to say it any more clearly. Everything you have is *fine*. The only problem is that the `ViewBag` property is not being populated because apparently the method that populates it is never called. Fix *that* and everything else will work.

Comment: I know but how to trigger that meethod. THanks

Comment: Are you expecting `@using (Html.BeginForm("GetClimbs" ...` in your view to call your `ActionResult GetClimbs(int? id){ //.. }` method?   Because, `BeginForm` is just an HTML Helper, it will not issue a request until submitted. I'm thinking this is where your confusion lies.

Comment: Yes, I know that. it is post action. But the issue is that climbs is null. Ofcourse I have the post method. But first the get method has to be triggered

Comment: Are you navigating to something like `/GetClimbs/1`, or are you trying to include the view as a partial? The latter will not work.

Comment: To be sure, what's your view filename ?

Comment: The tab is a partial view, yes

Comment: And the view where you call the partials is ```GetClimbs.cshtml``` right ? What is the url you use to test your page ?

Comment: Ok, I got the solution. Finally!! thanks everybody, see my updated post how I fixed